# Relative paths on 1st entry of server index file

Tags: php, html

On first entry to Apache server index page I create a horizontal header including the link "Home" that reloads the home page. On that page I have a column of links into other pages.

the file seq is:

server/new_index.php

```
<!-- WEB server entry point -->
<?php
#echo getcwd(),    "\n";
$path_parts = pathinfo(getcwd());
chdir("php2");
#This is really our current home page
include ('MainPage.php');
?>
```

MainPage.php starts with:

```
<?php # Hollywood Controls - MainPage
$page_title = 'Hollywood Controls';
include ('../inc/header.inc.htm');
?>
<?php
echo "1 ",getcwd() . "<br>";
include ('../inc/Categorymenu.inc.htm');
?>
```

header.inc.htm includes:

```
<div id="widemenu">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="../php2/MainPage.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="../php/AirCannons.php">Halloween Products</a></li>
<!--
    <li><a href="../php/Contact.php">Halloween Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="../php/AirCannons.php">Halloween Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="../php/Featured.php">Halloween Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="../php/OrderingInfo.php">Ordering</a></li>      -->
    <li><a href="../php/AboutUs.php">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="../php/Contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="../php/Privacy.php">Privacy</a></li>
    </ul>
    <?php include('../pp_buttons/view_cart.htm');?>

</div>
```

Categorymenu.inc.htm contains:

```
<?php
echo "3 ",getcwd() . "<br>";
#chdir("..\php2");
?>
<div id="tblmenu">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="2">Category</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="center" width="85%"><a href="PubArticles.php">Published Articles</a></td>
        <td>(1)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="center" width="85%"><a href="TekScopeBattery.php">Equipment Repair</a></td>
        <td>(1)</td>
        </tr><tr>
        <td align="center" width="85%"><a href="">Tear-downs</a></td>
        <td>(0)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="center" width="85%"><a href="Software.php">Software</a></td>
        <td>(1)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="center" width="85%"><a href="">PHP Scripts</a></td>
        <td>(0)</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

On the very first page load href="PubArticles.php" points to //server/PubArticles.php (which is incorrect, as the current directory is "php2").

If I reload the home page by clicking on the "Home" button in the horizontal header I get a different result. Now href="PubArticles.php" points to //server/php2/PubArticles.php (correct!).

I think I have sifted the relevant code from that full code. the echo getcwd() indicates that I am in "php2" on first entry and subsequent ones.

What am I missing here?

You can see this in action at www.hollywoodcontrols.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are outputting the table on `MainPage.php` by using `include ('../inc/Categorymenu.inc.htm');`. This *includes* the file on the page, which is essentially the same as *copying* the contents of that page into `MainPage.php`. As such, the links are relative to `MainPage.php`, rather than `Categorymenu.inc.htm`.

Considering the table links are going to be loaded by two files in two different directories, they're going to have two different *relative* paths. The best way around this is to make the table links relative to the root, by adding a trailing slash:

```
<a href="/php2/PubArticles.php">
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well, so obvious now when you point it out! I was certainly confused and an independent view point had none of that. tnx.

Comment: Glad to hear this answer solved the problem for you. Please don't forget to mark the solution as correct by clicking on the grey check below the vote buttons -- this removes it from the 'Unanswered questions' queue, and awards reputation to both the question asker and question answerer. Of course, in saying that, you are under no obligation to mark my answer (or any other answer) as correct, though it does help to keep things flowing smoothly :)